# "fopen()" no actualiza un archivo existente

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando en un código que publica artículos en una página. Este código funciona perfectamente al momento de crear el artículo, sin embargo, al intentar actualizarlo (publicando el mismo artículo con el mismo nombre pero con distinto contenido desde mi panel de admin), no se actualiza. Busco en la base de datos y la info es la misma (los cambios que se deberían hacer en el UPDATE del código no surten efecto) y al abrir el artículo desde el navegador, aparece igual que antes. ¿Me pueden ayudar a encontrar el error, por favor?

**Código PHP**

```
//Crear archivo html del artículo

    $nombreDelArchivo = url_amigable($titulo); //mando el título del artículo  a una función que me hace el nombre en "formato" url amigable (para que no haya problemas al abrir el artículo desde el navegador

    require_once("../includes/crearHTMLdeArticulo1.php");
    require_once("../includes/crearHTMLdeArticulo2.php");
    require_once("../includes/crearHTMLdeArticulo3.php");

    $contenidoArt = $contenido1 . "<title>" . $titulo . " - Level Up</title>" . $contenido2 . '
                <article id="contenedorArticuloCompleto">
                    <h1 id="tituloArtComp">' . $titulo . '</h1>
                    <div style="background-image:' . $foto . ';" id="imgArtComp"></div>
                    <div id="contenidoArtComp">' . $contenido . '</div>
                </article>
                ' . $contenido3;

//Hasta acá es una mezcla entre html y php para armar el contenido de la página

    $ruta = "../articles/" . $nombreDelArchivo . ".php";

    if (file_exists($ruta)){ //Acá debería entrar si la  ruta recién formada (conformada por ubicación del archivo y el nombre del mismo) es igual a alguna existente

        $query1 = "UPDATE articles SET titulo = '$titulo', img = '$foto', descripcion = '$descripcion', contenido = '$contenido' WHERE titulo = '$titulo'";

        if($resp1 = mysql_query($conexion, $query1)){

            $archivo = fopen($ruta, "w");
            fputs ($archivo, $contenidoArt);
            fclose ($archivo);

            $ok = true; //Pongo el valor "true" a la variable "ok" creada al inicio del código que tenía el valor predeterminado de "false"

            echo $ok;

        }else{
            echo $ok;
        }

    }else{

        $query2 = "INSERT INTO articles (titulo, img, descripcion, contenido) VALUES ('$titulo', '$foto', '$descripcion', '$contenido')";

        if($resp2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2)){

            $archivo = fopen($ruta, "w");

            fputs ($archivo, $contenidoArt);

            fclose ($archivo);

            $ok = true;

            echo $ok;
        }else{
            echo $ok;
        }
```

Comment: Algún mensaje de error? Si entiendo bien el problema es "doble"? No actualiza la base de datos y tampoco el archivo?

Comment: Si añades `error_reporting(E_ALL)` al principio del fichero PHP, ¿muestra algún error/aviso?

Comment: Damos por hecho que el fichero tiene permisos para sobreescribirse, vedad? Cambia el fputs por fwrite, se supone que es lo mismo, pero a mi siempre me ha fallado con fputs

Comment: Claro, no actualiza ni la base de datos ni el archivo. Pero no surge ningún error. Es como si entrase en la condición de file_exist pero no hace nada dentro.

Comment: Si, supongo que los tiene...Solamente es un archivo dentro de una carpeta acompañada de otros archivos de mi website. Usé el método "w" y el "x" par el fopen, pero ninguno parece dar resultado...Voy a probar con el fwrite a ver si ocurre algo. Gracias!!!

Comment: Por cierto, recuerda que tú código es vulnerable a sql injection; también la extensión mysql ya está obsoleta por lo que es mejor que portases tú código a mysqli o PDO.

Answer (score 1):

### El Título

El problema en el código gira en torno al título del artículo. Cuando cargas el objeto desde la base de datos guardas el mismo en la variable `$titulo`. Esta variable la utilizas para calcular la ruta del archivo. Ejemplo:

**Cuando cargas el artículo**
El valor de `$title` es `"Título original"` y por tanto la ruta al archivo que estás modificando es: `"../articles/titulo-original.php"`
**Cuando modificas el artículo**
El valor de `$title` pasa a ser `"Título nuevo"` por lo que la ruta al archivo cambia a `"../articles/titulo-nuevo.php"`.
Así, el método `file_exists("../articles/titulo-nuevo.php")` evalúa a **`false`**.

### Sentencia SQL

El fallo en la sentencía SQL que estás ejecutando se produce por el título:

```
$query1 = "UPDATE articles SET titulo = '$titulo', img = '$foto', descripcion = '$descripcion', contenido = '$contenido' WHERE titulo = '$titulo'";
```

**Si modificas el título del artículo**
En este punto estás pasando el valor de `$titulo` que ya ha sido modificado, por lo que cuando haces el update el filtro `WHERE titulo = '$titulo'` no encuentra el registro original.
Esto lo podrías resolver almacenando el título original del artículo en otra variable, por ejemplo `$titulo_original`. De esta forma la sentencia SQL quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$query1 = "UPDATE articles SET titulo = '$titulo', img = '$foto', descripcion = '$descripcion', contenido = '$contenido' WHERE titulo = '$titulo_original'";
```

Por otro lado `mysql_query()` *siempre* devolverá `true` si no se ha producido ningún error, aunque no modifique ningun registro en la base de datos. Para saber si, efectivamente, se ha afectado algún registro, usa el método `mysql_affected_rows()`. [mysql_affected_rows (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

> #### Documentación php.net sobre `mysql_affected_rows()`
>
> Devuelve el número de filas afectadas en caso de éxito, y -1 si la última consulta falló.

Así quedaría esta porción de código:

```
mysql_query($conexion, $query1);
if (mysql_affected_rows() !== 0) {
    // operaciones sobre el archivo
}
```

### Sobre los archivos

Por el trozo de código proporcionado deduzco que realizas escrituras simples sobre los archivos. Para esto puedes utilizar el método`file_put_contents()` que realiza `fopen()` y `fclose()` además de **sobreescribir el archivo** automáticamente. 
[file_put_contents (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php)

Tu código se reduciría a:

```
$resultado = file_put_contents($ruta, $contenidoArt, LOCK_EX);
if ( $resultado !== false) {
    // operaciones adicionales
}
```

En el tercer parámetro especifico el flag **`LOCK_EX`** que indica al método que debe obtener derecho exclusivo de acceso sobre el archivo.

### Recomendaciónes

Cuando modificas un artículo recomiendo guardar algunos parámetros del mismo justo al obtenerlo, de esta forma tienes más juego a la hora de guardar. Por ejemplo, eliminar el archivo con el título anterior.

También recomiendo utilizar un identificador invariable `ID` para los artículos, de esta forma no tienes que llevar un seguimiento del `$titulo_original` que he mencionado antes y la sentencia SQL quedaría tal que así:

```php
$query1 = "UPDATE articles SET titulo = '$titulo', img = '$foto', descripcion = '$descripcion', contenido = '$contenido' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Esto también te hará más cómodas las tareas de carga y eliminación de los artículos pues no tendrás que trabajar con cadenas. Pero esto solo si estas tareas se vuelven más complejas.

Y como bien ha mencionado @Hackerman, recomiendo cambiar a *mysqli* o *PDO*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes mal esta parte

$query1 = "UPDATE articles SET titulo = '$titulo', img = '$foto', descripcion = '$descripcion', contenido = '$contenido' WHERE titulo = '$titulo'";

prueba con esto

$query1 = "UPDATE articles SET titulo = '".$titulo."', img = '".$foto."', descripcion = '".$descripcion."', contenido = '".$contenido."' WHERE titulo = '".$titulo."'";